# Difference between MACHINE and TERMINAL in V$SESSION table

Tags: database, oracle

I am using the following query to know the blocked sessions. Can anyone tell me the difference between machine and terminal column in the following query in real-time scenario? My Oracle is installed on the windows machine.

`select distinct a.sid waiting_session, a.serial#, d.sql_text waiting_query, a.BLOCKING_SESSION blocking_session, a.process, a.machine, a.terminal, a.program, a.inst_id, ROUND(a.last_call_et/60) blocktime, a.lockwait, to_char(a.logon_time,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from gv$session a join gv$sql d on a.sql_id=d.sql_id left join gv$active_session_history b on a.blocking_session=b.session_id left join gv$sql c on c.sql_id=b.sql_id where a.con_id in (select con_id from V$MYSTAT) and a.blocking_session != 0 order by blocktime desc`

Answer (score 1):

From [Oracle documentation](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/identifying-host-names-and-addresses)

> TERMINAL - The operating system terminal name for the client. This is
>   often set to the client machine name.
>
> MACHINE - The operating system
>   name for the client machine. This may include the domain name if
>   present.

`MACHINE`

- is the name of the computer that you can see in the system property of the computer.

`TERMINAL`

- may be the same as `MACHINE` but it does not include the Domain name of the computer, even if it is present in the machine name.
- or it can be null if the terminal name is not set